# How to deal with a failure API call with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am accessing 3 API's and aggregating it's data onto my page. Currently if one of the API calls fails (perhaps the site is offline) the execution stops and the page does not contain any data.

I want to keep executing the remaining API calls and just ignore the one that failed silently. How can I do that?

```
myApp.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $q, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.allTest = function () {
        var first = $http.get('/api/drawings/'),
            second = $http.get('/api/procedures/'),
            third = $http.get('/api/sharepoint/');

        $q.all([first, second, third]).then(function (result) {
            var tmp = [];
            angular.forEach(result, function (response) {
                tmp.push(response.data);
            });
            return tmp;
        }).then(function (result) {
            $scope.combinedResult = result; // result in combinedResult
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need proper error handling, which for example can be done via callbacks, so that

```
                $http.get('/api/drawings/').then(
                    (response:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>) => {
                        success(response);
                    },
                    (response:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>) => {
                        error(response);
                    }
                );
```

If success - continue execution, otherwise handle the error.

Comment: I still want to continue execution of the other 2 API calls and ignore the error (by ignore I mean silently log or try to reload that API call again)

Comment: Encapuslate those API calls in services, so instead of calling them directly in the controller, call via service where fail will be handled and logged as you said. And of course your next two calls also needs to have the same handling, so that you can call them consequently. So it will be something  `apiService.retrieveDrawings`, `apiService.retrieveProcedures`, `apiService.retrieveSharepoint`, and each `retrieve*` method will handle errors and log.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the guidance. This worked out very well. I gracefuily ignore offline or errors in the service as sometimes happen and still render data to the screen that does not have errors.